# What happens on a disapproval roll of 0 or less?

Tags: cleric, dungeon-crawl-classics-rpg

The Deity Disapproval table on page 122 lists the penalties for a Disapproval roll of 1 through 20+.

However, it appears to me that a roll of 0 or less is not only possible, but highly likely.  The roll is

- Nd4 where N is the number on the failed spell check
- Less the cleric's Luck modifier

Since Luck is a basic stat (within 3-18) it seems like Disapproval rolls will be 0 or less until the cleric suffers several failures in a day (hence increasing N).

Does that mean there is no actual Disapproval?

Answer (score 3):

Since the rules don't actually say, you're going to have to make a judgement call.  If it were up to me, I'd say that *a roll of zero has no effect*.

Here's why I'd make that call:

### The results on the table aren't predictable.

Imagine if it said:

- roll 1: chant for 10 minutes
- roll 2: chant for 20 minutes
- roll 3: chant for 40 minutes
- roll 4: chant for 80 minutes

Even without a listed result for a roll of zero, you could still predict that it would say "chant for 5 minutes", following a regular, predicatble pattern.

### The results mostly tend to get weaker as the roll goes down.

Though the table isn't predictable, the results at low rolls tend to be much weaker than the results at high rolls.  *Chant for 10 minutes, once you're out of battle* isn't a very hard thing to do.  *Lose 1 point of Strength, Agility, and Stamina due to illness* is a much stronger effect.

Answer (score 3):

It's Luck *modifier* (-3 to +3) that gets subtracted, not Luck score.  For example, a cleric with a positive Luck modifier and a low d4 result on their first Disapproval roll would have to deal with this 0 or lower situation.

DCC isn't written with the kind of exacting technical detail that provides bounds checking on its tables.  Disapproval is a very common occurrence that's also supposed to be Bad News that the cleric must deal with as soon as possible.  Completely ignoring a lower than 1 result doesn't express this at all.

As a DCC Judge, you're empowered to make your own rulings about what happens in this situation that isn't entirely covered by the given rules. Personally, I would treat the result as a 1.  You could choose to make the player reroll instead, or you could come up with your own results for -2, -1, and 0.